# Submit form on radio button click - Submit form and perform other actions on radio click

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery question concerning Radio buttons and forms.

I have tabbed content setup with 5 tabs setup with a form in each tab.

Each form consists of 5 radio buttons and a submit button.

I have my jQuery setup to validatte that a selection has been made first, then submit the form using AJAX, close the current tab (slideUp) and open the next tab (slideDown).

What I would prefer to do is remove the submit buttons and submit the form on the click of any of the radiobuttons.  So that clicking a radio button submits the form, closes the current tab and opens the next.

What do I need to do to make it so that clicking any one of the radio buttons will submit the forma and close the tabs.  My jQuery code is posted below.

```
$("#selfAss1").validate({
    invalidHandler: function(e, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1
                ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted below'
                : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields.  They have been highlighted below';
            $("div.error span").html(message);
            $("div.error").show();
        } else {
            $("div.error").hide();
        }
    },
    onkeyup: false,
    submitHandler: function() {
            $.post('/_action.php', $("#selfAss1").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('.pane1').slideUp('slow');
                    $('#result1').html(data);
                    $('.pane2').slideDown('slow');


            });
    },
    debug:true
});
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The transition from one slide to the next is handled by your `submitHandler`, so all the radio buttons need to do is submit the form on click, with that in mind:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

A couple of notes; firstly I used the attribute selector here, you may want to change that to a class or something more specific for your needs. Secondly, you may also want to include a 'return' method to allow people to change their selections. With this method, if you click once, that's it.

Comment: My tabs allow them to go back already by clicking them.  I only posted a small portion of my code.. there is quite a bit of other code there as well.  Let me try this..

Comment: This worked great, it works well with my existing code by the looks of it.  The beauty of it was the "closest" ... As there are 5 forms on the page.

Comment: You would be better to use change event instead of click so that it works with wrapped labels

Comment: @JohnMagnolia You're indeed correct. Updated this very old answer for you.

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

```
<input name="myRadio" type="radio" value="1" onchange="this.form.submit()"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

try

```
 <input type="radio" name="something" onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').submit();"/>
```

or

```
 <input type="radio" name="something" onclick="this.form.submit()">
```

in jquery try something like

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    $("form id or class").submit();
});
```

Comment: unrelated but this showed up in google at only 39 minutes past posting!  thats amazing google.

Comment: @MichaelDeMutis even than i have saw some time less than half a minute but never got solution how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try This!!

```
 $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
$('input[type=submit]').click();});
```