# I need the answer from a form to immediately redirect to another form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, if-statement, redirect

I have a one question radio button form. I want the answer to immediately redirect to page A if the answer is A or redirect to page B if the answer is B. I know that the answer probably relies on javascript, but I am fairly new to coding and javascript is my Achilles' heel.

I have the form selecting and a basic if else statement - just not sure how to tie the two together. Some other questions here were helpful, just not enough to fully help me put something together. Here is my current code:

```
<?php
echo '<form id="gate" action="index.php" method="post">';
echo '<p>question<br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="gateway" value="A">answer A<br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="gateway" value="No">answer B<br>';
echo '</p>';

// branching for different forms
if($gateway=="Yes") {
    header ('answer Yes url');
} else if($gateway=="No") {
    header ('answer No url');
}    
echo '</form>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I currently click on Yes or No and nothing happens. I would love some help connecting A and B to my statement. I would love to be able to do it without the user having to click Submit - have it redirect when they make the choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should check if request is a POST, then fetch your 'gateway' from the post.

Note that after a redirect in php you have to stop the script with a `die()` or with `exit()`.

Below is an example

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    if ($_POST['gateway'] == "Yes") {
        header("Location: <YOUR YES URL>");
        die();
    } else {
        header("Location: <YOUR NO URL>");
        die();
    }
}
```

To achieve the form submit on checking the radio input, your best option would be to put `onclick="this.form.submit();"` on your radio inputs

Comment: I have edited the code to the following: 
`code`
echo '<input type="radio" name="gateway" value="Yes" onclick="this.form.submit();"> Yes<br>';
echo '<input type="radio" name="gateway" value="No" onclick="this.form.submit();"> No<br>';
echo '</p>';
if (isset($_POST)) {
 if($_POST['gateway'] == "Yes") {
   echo 'This sucks!';
 //   header('url');
   die();

 } else {
   echo 'I wish this would work!';
  //  header ('url');
   die();
         }
    }

</form>
include '../footer.php';
`code`

Comment: It is working part way - the correct echos are showing when a choice is made, but url does not redirect and the footer at the end does not get included when commented instead of remarks.

Comment: Please make sure that you make the php redirect correct. It should be like this  header('Location : https://google.com')

Comment: You could check the answer from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112373/php-page-redirect/2112394#2112394

Comment: Thanks! I am getting the headers already sent message so I will have to fix that. Hopefully that will be the final error.  I appreciate all the help!

Answer (score -1):

you may try:

```
echo '<input type="radio" name="gateway" value="A" onchange="this.form.submit()">answer A<br>';
```

as suggested in [Submit form on radio button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13126501/submit-form-on-radio-button-click-submit-form-and-perform-other-actions-on-rad)